# Is it possible to use an existing grid when creating an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, itemscontrol

I'm trying to create a layout where both the number of rows and the number of columns are dynamic, like shown below:

[image]

I am looking to have all of the controls hosted in one grid so that I can get tabbing working from top to bottom, left to right. The code which I am trying to get working is shown below:

```
<Grid base:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=dx:DXWindow}, Path=Groups.Count}" Name="EnclosingGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Labels-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" ItemsPanel="{Binding ElementName=EnclosingGrid}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=FieldName}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!--Process fields-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}" ItemsPanel="{Binding ElementName=EnclosingGrid}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding ParentRow.RowIndex}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

I've tried setting the `ItemsPanel` attribute to the enclosing grid, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Is the only way really to set up the grid as a `ItemsPanelTemplate` inside the `ItemsControl`?

Are there any other approaches? Or would I have to roll my own `ItemsControl`?

Answer (score 0):

**ItemsPanel** property type is **ItemsPanelTemplate** so you can't bind this property directly to some existing control.

You can think about this property as a kind of factory class, which is supposed to provide container control for items.
This is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) literally says about this type: *Specifies the panel that the **ItemsPresenter creates** for the layout of the items of an ItemsControl.*

Comment: Could you please include a link to the MSDN that says this?

Comment: @IronMan84 check updated text - I've put a link behind "MSDN" word.

Comment: You can use some grid-like control, for example ListView (with View=GridView), or DataGrid. I think latter is more likely to be the viable option for your task.